# I can't add Skype logo in moderncv theme via fontawesome

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, moderncv, fontawesome

I'm trying to add the skype logo to my CV using `moderncv` and `fontawesome package`. I'm running with `XeLaTeX`, but even with `LuaLaTex` doesn't work. This is my code and my output. I checked on `fontawesome.com` and the `Unicode` used is right.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
%\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}                 % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                % idem

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newcommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths                             % required when changes are made to page layout lengths

\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           

\firstname{XXXX}
\familyname{\\ \\XXXX}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{XXXXX}{XXXXXX}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{XXXXXXX}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\phone{xxxxxx}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\fax{xxxxxx}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{XXXXXX}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{\linkedinsocialsymbol \faSkype XXXXXX}
```

[image: output]

Someone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never load `inputenc` or `fontenc` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. And `\faSkype` is already defined by the package.  The following document works for me with LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\faSkype
\end{document}
```

For reasons I don't understand, XeLaTeX sometimes has problems finding fonts in the `texmf` tree unless you specify the filename, so if for some reason you *must* use XeLaTeX and not LuaLaTeX, you can load the package code manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\FA{FontAwesome.otf}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\faicon}[1]{%
  {\csname faicon@#1\endcsname}}
\input{fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex}
\input{fontawesomesymbols-xeluatex.tex}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\faSkype
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Both solutions don't work for me.  With XeLaTeX I don't find fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex and with LuaLaTex I have an error where I put \faSkype (Undefined control sequence. \faSkype). Probably because I don't defined  the command explicitly. Maybe the problem is with modernCV? (I have to use the symbol outside of Document).

Comment: @TheZone Do the minimal documents in my answer not work?  (Apart from modernCV)?  You didn't post compilable code with `moderncv` but my quick test with it worked. Maybe you have an old version of `fontawesome`. Mine is `2016/05/15 v4.6.3.1` (TL 2017).

Comment: No, I tried now (with article). Same errors of my code. How can I see the version? It is possible, they are several years that I don't use latex (2015).

Comment: @TheZone Add `\listfiles` to the first line of the test document and see what version of `fontawesome` you have.

Comment: Package: fontawesome 2013/05/10 v3.1.1 font awesome icons

Comment: @TheZone Well there's the problem.  That's super old. (I'm guessing this is a Linux packaged TeX distribution.) Can you update your distribution? Or you could install a local version from CTAN.

Comment: How can I uptade the package? I downloaded the .rar locally from CTAN

Comment: @TheZone See [How to have local package override default package](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357)

Comment: Regarding the necessity to use file name in XeTeX, it's mentioned in the `fontspec` documentation (see Section 1.2 of v2.6g). I submitted a [Pull Request](https://github.com/xdanaux/fontawesome-latex/pull/16) to make `fontawesome` compatible with XeLaTeX a while ago, but no response from the maintainer as of now.

Comment: @AlanMunn At this path C:\texlive\2014\texmf-dist\tex\latex\fontawesome I have now the .sty and three .tex updated (fontawesomesymbols - generic, pdflatex, xeluatex) but the problem remain. ! LaTeX Error: File `fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex' not found. (with xelatex and lualatex)

Comment: @TheZone The linked question said to put things into `~/texmf/tex/latex/` not into the main distribution tree.

Comment: @AlanMunn from texlive I have two folder. 2014 and texmf-local. you refer to texmf-local? Inside that folder I have tex\latex\local and it's empty. I tried put in local a folder named fontawesome with .sty and the three .tex inside but nothing changed.

Comment: @TheZone No, make a folder `texmf` in your home directory, with subdirectories `tex/latext/fontawesome` and put the files there.

Comment: @AlanMunn Doesn't work. with 2014 and texmf-local now I created texmf with the subdirectories and the files inside. From the error I can see that it continue to search the package in what you called main distribution tree. In that folder it doesn't find .tex files even if I put them in the folder.

Comment: @TheZone Are you sure you made a `~/texmf` folder? (Not inside `texlive`, but just in your home directory.)

Comment: What do you mean with home folder? The folder texlive? Or C:?

Comment: @TheZone I mean C:

Comment: @AlanMunn I did, but Xelatex and Lualatex contunue to search the package in the main folder, and I got the same error (I consider the "t" in latext in your past comment a typo).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75370/discussion-between-alan-munn-and-thezone).